# Find Quarter Months Based on Payroll Cycle

Tags: sql-server-2012

This would be in the "where" clause...how do I find quarters based on a payroll cycle? Our payroll cycle starts on the 25th of the quarter month and ends on the 10th of the quarter month. For example...
The 2nd quarter starts on 4/25/2016 and ends on 7/10/2016.

Comment: can you gie the start and end dates for all quarters for 1 year

Comment: 1st quarter start is 1/25/16 end is 4/10/16; 2nd quarter start is 4/25/16 end is 7/10/16; 3rd quarter start is 7/25/16 end is 9/10/16; 4th quarter start is 9/25/16 end is 1/10/17

Comment: Thanks. And just to clarify you are trying to see what quarter a given Payroll date falls in, correct?

Comment: what about dates inbetween? For instance, 4/20/2016

Comment: I should have been more clear on my question. I am looking for the total amount of commissions for each individual within a quarter. So, I was looking for something like, "where payroll_month between .... and ....". Looking at the 2nd quarter, the payroll_month would be the month number or "4". Generally speaking, the 25th represents the 1st of the month to the 15th. The 10th pay period is from the 16th to the 30th. So, looking at the 2nd quarter - the month number would start at 4 and the end with 7. These would be pay period dates of   4/11 to  7/10. neck deep in mud yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's kind of hard to understand completely what you are doing but here is something that should work. You can edit the dates to fit what you want but I made it based off what you stated.

```
--This is just test data... you can use your own table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#payroll') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #payroll

CREATE TABLE #payroll (dates date)

INSERT INTO #payroll (dates) VALUES
('1/1/2016'),
('1/16/2016'),
('2/4/2016'),
('3/3/2016'),
('3/19/2016'),
('4/18/2016'),
('5/6/2016'),
('6/4/2016'),
('6/29/2016'),
('7/4/2016'),
('7/31/2016'),
('8/9/2016'),
('9/1/2016'),
('10/3/2016'),
('10/19/0216'),
('11/4/2016'),
('11/21/2016'),
('12/2/2016'),
('1/1/2016'),
('1/8/2017'),
('1/21/2017')


--variable for what ever quarter you want to limit on. 1-4
declare @Quarter int
set @Quarter = 4


--Year that you are focused on. If left to NULL it uses the current year
declare @Year int
set @Year = NULL

IF @Year IS NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SET @Year = Year(GETDATE())
    END

--Date parameters that we will use to filter
declare @startDate date = null
declare @endDate date = null

--logic to set your quarters
set @startDate = case
                    when @Quarter = 1 then '1/25/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
                    when @Quarter = 2 then '4/25/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
                    when @Quarter = 3 then '7/25/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
                    when @Quarter = 4 then '9/25/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
                end 
set @endDate = case 
                    when @Quarter = 1 then '4/10/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
                    when @Quarter = 2 then '7/10/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
                    when @Quarter = 3 then '9/10/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
                    when @Quarter = 4 then '1/10/' + CAST((@Year + 1)as varchar(4))
                end 


--run it to test results
select *
from #payroll
where dates between @startDate and @endDate
```